# WatiN: GetAttributeValue("value") does not return value

Tags: c#, .net, testing, automated-tests, watin

I intend to display the value of *value* attribute from the **Google Translate** menu of all the languages. It is represented by the *left* list of the page.

This is the code I am running and nothing is displayed on the console (apart from the new lines). What could be wrong?

```
using System;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IE ie = new IE("https://translate.google.com/");

            Div selectLanguage = ie.Div(Find.ById("gt-sl-sugg"));
            foreach (var lang in selectLanguage.ChildrenOfType<Div>())
                Console.WriteLine(lang.GetAttributeValue("value"));

            ie.Close();

            Console.Read();
        }
     }
}
```

**WatiN: 2.1.0**

Comment: `value` is not an attribute of these divs. Are you sure you don't mean `innerHTML` or `innerText`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I don't want the _text_, but the attribute _value_.

Comment: You know what? I did not double check before that comment. They do have a value attribute. My bad.

Comment: Ok, I see. Replace `("value")` with `("Value")`, For some reason all the attributes have the first letter capitalized.

Comment: Wow! You are right. Thank you! It works. But why? When I press **F12** in my browser, the attributes don't show to have the first letter capitalized.

Comment: My guess is watin deserializes the DOM elements into objects, and since it is pretty standard to have property names with that naming convention, it does it that way.

Comment: Do you know links, that would offer a proper and consistent documentation for WatiN? I am a beginner, and this problem took me a lot of time.

Comment: The only documentation I could find is http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/WatiN/WatiN.Core/Document  which is mostly incomplete. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. That one I knew about it. How do I set this question to "**Solved**"?

Comment: The last question: how have you found out that the attributes have the first letter capitalized?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say this on my last message. I set a breakpoint on the `Console.WriteLine(lang.GetAttributeValue("Value"));` line, and debugged and noticed that all other properties and attributes were like that and gave it a try. I can post my comment if you want to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `("value")` with `("Value")`, For some reason all the attributes have the first letter capitalized. My guess is watin deserializes the DOM elements into objects, and since it is pretty standard to have property names with that naming convention (PascalCase), it does it that way for these objects too.